# Logging an Exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, logging, apache-commons

I am using commons logging in a Java application, and I want to log the exception from the stack trace.

```
catch( Exception exception ) {
         logger.error( "FailedCreateActivityFunction Exception Occured : " , exception );
         throw new EngineException( getMessage( ERROR_FailedCreateActivityFunction, FunctionName ), exception );
      }
```

**Will this throw the exception twice ? If yes how to fix it ?**

Whats the difference between using it as this way using **+ exception** instead of **, exception**

```
logger.error( "FailedCreateActivityFunction Exception Occured : " + exception );
```

Comment: the difference of using + exception instead of , exception can be seen at the java doc
"public void error(Object message, Throwable t)"
the error function can accept only message or message + throwable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it will not throw exception twice. This code will throw only EngineException.

You should avoid logging and throwing exceptions, do only one thing. Log and throw is an antipattern. You can read more about exception handling here: [Exception Handling Antipatterns](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-983543).

Difference between those two ways of executing error method is:

- in logger.error(String msg, Throwable t) - you pass object, so logging framework has more information, and can show you full stack trace
- in logger.error(String msg) - you create String, no additional information is passed to logging framework

Comment: Can you please specify which way should I use in this scenario `+ exception` or `, exception` ?

Any other way to push that stacktrace to logger ?

Comment: You should generally use `, exception` way. And as far I know, all good logging frameworks push stack trace to logger when you use it that way.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't throw it twice.

The [first method](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#error%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) will print your message AND the exception's stacktrace.

The [second method](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#error%28java.lang.Object%29) will print only your message AND the exception message (invoking throwable.toString() that [returns a short description of the error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#toString%28%29)), without the stacktrace.